# How to mark input field text in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, input

I have an angular page with an input field in its template.
I want to mark the text of the input field when a function is called.
when I say "mark the text" I mean (see picture below)

[image]

I got the element as an `HTMLInputElement` object with the `ViewChild` option, and I tried several methods like: focus, select, setSelectionRange and more...
And the result was always the same: `ERROR TypeError: mailInputField.focus is not a function` (not only for focus, also for the select and setSelectionRange etc...)

The input field in the template is `<input #mailInputField [value]="mail">`. in the `.ts` file the view child is: `@ViewChild("mailInputField") mailInputField! : HTMLInputElement;`, and my function called `selectMailText()` is (meanwhile) something like `this.mailInputField.focus();`

How can I mark this text?

Comment: Did you try typing it?@ViewChild('mailInputField') input: ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>;

Comment: I'm really not understanding what you mean by "mark" a field.  Do you mean that you want to set the focus in a field when something happens, or are you wanting an event to be called when the field gains focus?

Comment: @FiniteLooper, I actually wrote it and even added a picture. "Mark the text", for me is that the text is marked like the situation in which someone double-clicked the text and it has the blue backgroung. About your second question, I want to mark the text when a function `markText()` is called. All what this function does, is to mark the text. When this function will be called? It doesn't matter for my answer... I want the ability, and I will write a code (later) that will use this ability. That's all

Comment: @Loop it is a good idea, I tried it just now, but still the `select()` method only focus the input and not select the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found a way to do it.

The way is: `setTimeout(() => {this.mailInputField.nativeElement.select();}, 1);`.

Which means:

1. use `setTimeout` for 1 milisecond so that the changes will occur after everything is fully loaded.
2. use `nativeElement` and in the `@ViewChild` use `ElementRef<HTMLInputElement>` as @Loop said
3. use (only) the `select()` method

Comment: Not use the "1" miliseconds. When Angular find a setTimeout, Angular "repaint" and **after**, execute the action, so it's unnecessary the 1:`setTimeout(() => {this.mailInputField.nativeElement.select();})`. NOTE: The "setTimeout" is used when you need this "repaint", e.g. you have an input under a *ngIf, you change the condition, Angular "repaint", and after, you can focus it. But if the "input" is yet, you needn't use setTimeout

Answer (score 1):

I think the word you are looking for is "selected" or "highlighted", not "marked"

Check out [the docs for the `.select()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/select)

You need to `.focus()` and then `.select()`

```ts
selectText() {
  this.mailInputField.focus();
  this.mailInputField.select();
}
```